# How to get my macro to paste to a specific cell

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I have a macro that copies an entire row based on a specific cell value and pastes those rows into another sheet. However, on the second sheet it pastes to cell B1, but I would like it to paste to B2 so that I may include headers.

(Test sheet is from B:E)

```
Dim C As Range
Dim Test As Worksheet
Dim Pastesheet As Worksheet
Dim j As Integer

'Find the last row with data in column C
LR = Worksheets("Test Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Set Test = Worksheets("Test Sheet")  ' Copy From this sheet
Set Pastesheet = Worksheets("Inventory")  ' to this sheet

'look at every cell in D2 onwards

j = 1

For Each C In Test.Range("D2:D" & LR)

If C.Value = True Then

        'Copy code

        C.EntireRow.Copy Pastesheet.Rows(j) ' copy the row from column D that meets that requirements

        j = j + 1

    End If

Next C


End Sub
```

Comment: Change `j = 1` to `j = 2`.  Or start at 1 but use `j+1` as @pnuts suggested.  Or move the `j=j+1` line before the `Copy` line.  Any of those will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simply changing your paste row to start from 2, so `j = 2` rather than `j = 1`

I will also add that if you don't need to pull the format of the cells in the copied selection (aka you only need the values), I'd recommend avoiding the use of the Copy function, as this can get quite slow over a large data set.  If that is indeed the case, the following would work quite nicely:

```
...

j = 1

For Each C In Test.Range("D2:D" & LR)
    If C.Value = True Then

        Pastesheet.Range(Pastesheet.Cells(j, 2),Pastesheet.Cells(j, 5)).Value = Test.Range(Test.Cells(C.Row, 2),Test.Cells(C.Row, 5)).Value

        j = j + 1
    End If
Next C

...
```

**Note:** I am assuming that the data you'd like to copy is only in 4 columns since you stated that the data went from B:E, but this can be adjusted to capture more columns as needed simply by adjusting the column numbers

The code itself is slightly longer and less elegant looking than the paste command, but for a large data set this could save quite a bit of processing time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That's good advice. One problem, after trying that code only column 2 from Test gets pasted into Pastesheet. How can I make it so columns 2-5 continuous are pasted?

Comment: I believe I solved it.   
`Pastesheet.Range(Pastesheet.Cells(j, 2), Pastesheet.Cells(j, 5)).Value = Test.Range(Test.Cells(C.Row, 2), Test.Cells(C.Row, 5)).Value `

Comment: Yup, I mixed up rows and columns.  Good catch (editting the answer now to fix that)